# Force ie8 to read noscript tags

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I've used a Drupal 7 theme to build a website. After everything is tested and live the client and my boss tell me this site needs to work in ie8. This is a problem because the theme includes features only supported in ie9 and up. There are noscript fallbacks built in that could work if displayed, but I can't figure out how to make them show.

Below is the URL, any suggestions for making this work in ie8?

http://museumandgardens.com/portfolio/col3

Comment: Um, noscript only runs when JavaScript is disabled....so why would you need to force them?

Comment: @epascarello He's trying to essentially display a script-less version of the site. It'll be less dynamic, but it might still work. That said, the issue could also involve plugin HTML/CSS requirements going beyond Javascript. (Also, please inform your client that if he's on Windows XP, he is now likely contributing to Lizard Squad's global botnet.)

Comment: @Katana314 where is the like button on this site? lol

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure the problem is not with the way IE8 handles the CSS?

If it is having the javascript that is not working correctly, you can avoid including certain sections of it using javascript browser conditional statements, show [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/cc2.shtml).

I would recommend only cutting out the sections that don't work correctly, rather than trying to force it into not using any scripts if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is in some plugin using javascript canvas, which in not supported by IE8. Luckily IE has this fancy feature called [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't exactly remember how it works, so I suggest two alternatives, one of them should work:

```
<img class="borealis image-style-640x480 borealis-js placeholder" data-borealis-... src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/borealis/borealis_ri/images/blank.gif" alt=""/>
<noscript><!--[if lt IE 9]></noscript><![endif]-->
    <img class="borealis image-style-640x480" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://museumandgardens.com/sites/default/files/styles/640x480/public/portfolio/WeddingFlowerWindow_2.jpeg?itok=rLdnw9KQ" width="640" height="480" alt="" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]><noscript><![endif]--></noscript>
```

(close `<noscript>` tag immediatelly in ie8)

or

```
<img class="borealis image-style-640x480 borealis-js placeholder" data-borealis-... src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/borealis/borealis_ri/images/blank.gif" alt=""/>
<noscript>
    <img class="borealis image-style-640x480" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://museumandgardens.com/sites/default/files/styles/640x480/public/portfolio/WeddingFlowerWindow_2.jpeg?itok=rLdnw9KQ" width="640" height="480" alt="" />
</noscript>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <img class="borealis image-style-640x480" typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://museumandgardens.com/sites/default/files/styles/640x480/public/portfolio/WeddingFlowerWindow_2.jpeg?itok=rLdnw9KQ" width="640" height="480" alt="" />
<![endif]-->
```

(duplicate `<noscript>` contents inside conditional comment for ie8)

**EDIT:** Better soultion would be to modify javascript code to check if canvas is supported - run fancy animations, otherwise - fallback to static image. But probably it would be too hard to patch 3rd party library's code.